# Titanium SDK (vers 12.1.2 GA) in VSCode hangs on Cleaning Xcode derived data. What can I do about this?

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

Xcode, Android studio, VSCode and Titanium are up to date. The Android Simulator is running like it should. The iOS-Simulator (regardless of device and iOS version) starts up like normal but hangs on the stage of "Cleaning Xcode derived Data" and even after literall hours nothing happends, neither a timeout of sorts nor an error message. After an extensive session of researching on the internet I didn't find anything that would even remotely help me out. Does someone know what to do here?

I already restarted VSCode, looked in Xcode if the simulator works at all (it did, without throwing an error) and lastly restarted the device. I even installed a older iOS Version (I had only 15.5 and installed 15.0) to make sure this wasn't the issue. None of these did anything to help me out.

Comment: did you try to build it without VSCode just using the CLI `ti build -p ios` ? What Xcode version are you using?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't help. I left it running for approx. 15mins. I got the debug output but nothing more unfortunately, it still stopped. I'm using Xcode  Version 13.4.1.(13F100).

Comment: that is a very old release! You have to build with Xcode 14.1 for the app store. So try to update Xcode and make sure to set it it `Xcode preferences->locations->Command Line Tools`

Comment: I did exactly that. Yet the issue is still there.

Comment: can you build with `ti build -p ios -l trace` and upload the log somewhere? `ti info` would also help

Comment: I just restarted the device to make sure the paths are right and it works flawless now.

Comment: nice! Glad it work